# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: запятая

Подумай вот о чем.

Comment: @Charmante_K, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

После ''подумай'' отсутствует пауза, а следовательно, запятая не требуется.